# HttpContext.Current.Session is null in Web API controller in IIS 7.5 but is ok in IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, session, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5, iis-express

My code runs fine when launched from Visual Studio (2012) in debug mode - which I think uses IIS Express but when I publish it to IIS 7.5.7600 the session object is null. I know this because I've placed debug calls to my logger.

I've tried different methods to set SessionStateBehavior to Required:
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Required);

I've placed this in several places:
1. Application_Start()
2. Application_PostAuthenticateRequest()
3. Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()

Seems like #2 and #3 get called in debug mode/IIS Express but not in my QA IIS 7.5 server.

I appreciate the help.

Update - here's part of my web.config:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" enableVersionHeader="false" executionTimeout="200" maxRequestLength="12288" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="180">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>

<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="Session" />
    <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
    <add name="ResponseHeaderRewriter" type="MoveShakeWebApp.Utilities.Security.ResponseHeaderRewriter" />
    <remove name="BundleModule" />
    <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
  </modules>
```

Update #2 - I tested setting and retrieving a session var in a view controller - it's a public ActionResult - and it works fine.

Comment: 1- You should not manipulate session in `Application_Start`. 2- You can run it on local IIS in VS. 3- Did you remove and add `SessionStateModule` in `Web.config` ?

Comment: Yes I add and remove the SessionStateModule in the web.config. I'll paste snippets from the web.config as an update above.

Comment: @LanP Recreate your application (virtual app) on IIS.